# Inconsistency in number of samples

Tags: python

I did run the following code on split datasets to check they were the same length after the split:

```py
print(len(labels), len(y_train), len(y_val), len(y_test))
```

```py
print(len(features), len(X_train), len(X_val), len(X_test))
```

it returned 1074 644 215 215 for both

When I run logistic regression on the train set, it returns as error "Inconsistent number of samples 645, 644"

How can that be and how can I make them consistent?

Comment: Related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/train-test-split-error-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-sam

Answer (score 0):

It was returning this error because I added header=None while defining features and labels after the split. Once I undid that, the error was solved.

```
tr_features = pd.read_csv('address.csv')
tr_labels = pd.read_csv('address.csv', header=None)
```